# All prime ideals in $\mathbb Z_n$ [proof verification]

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

I know that there are several ways of getting the ideals in $R=\mathbb Z_n$. I am intersted if mine is correct:

All prime ideals $I\subset R$ correspond to an Ideal $J\subset \mathbb Z$ satisfying $J\supset n\mathbb Z$. Since all subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ are known to be of the form $m\mathbb Z$ we can conclude that $J=m\mathbb Z$ where $m\mid n$. This $J$ again corresponds to $I=J/n\mathbb Z=m\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Now we see with the isomorphism theorem that $R/I\cong \mathbb Z_m$, so:

$I\subset R$ is prime $\Leftrightarrow$ $R/I$ is an integral domain $\Leftrightarrow$ $m$ is a prime.

> 1. All ideals in R are of the form $m\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$
> 2. All prime ideals in $R$ are of the form $p\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ where $p$ is a prime.

Is that correct? Detailed enough?

Comment: You might add, for 2., that $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$.

Comment: Oh yeah, sure.. I wouldn't know what $p\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is anyway if  $p$ wasn't a divisor of $n$.

Comment: The important expression in my comment was ‘prime divisor’ as a whole – just to put it in ordinary language.